What does the initial part of NetCDF(.nc) file refers to?
I am a student majoring Computer Science.
Recently, I am struggling to open and extract specific data for my research from large amount of NetCDF files.
But there seems to be some problem processing file via API, and other viewers.
These are methods I've tried and failed :

Python module 'netcdf4' : processing with python code


error occurs "Invalid argument"


command module 'ncdump' : "$ ncdump -h file_I_want_to_open.nc"


error occurs "Invalid argument"


viewer 'Panoply'


error occurs "Misformed netCDF file - dim magic number wrong"


viewer 'Qgit'


error occurs "unvalid file"

These are every information I've got :

NetCDF files were produced from Weather Research & Forecast (WRF) Model v4.4.
Each files' size is over 5 Giga bytes, and their file format is '64-bit offset'.
NetCDF file is not corrupted, and is in complete form.
NetCDF file is combined with ASCII/binary encoded data.

According to the error occured by "Panoply", it seems to be something in dimension data. Since same error also occurs when I only try to dump only the header of the file("ncdump -h ..."), there certainly some difference in metadata part because of the customized WRF model.
What I want to ask/ Where I need a solution :

Is there any viewers/api for opening/extracting customized WRF model output files in NetCDF format?
Is it possible to see which part of my NetCDF file is not matching up for normal viewers or APIs?
Is there any mechanism(library/module) for converting data file with "ASCII(tag)" -- "binary(data)" into "ASCII(tag)" -- "readible data" ?
Or is there more smarter way to solve this out?

Sorry for my bad english, it must have made my question vague..
But I desperately need some helps to solve this out.
Thanks always.
+2024/12/16)
Sorry for my unsufficient information in my question. It is obvious it will be a dumb way to just ask 'error occured! Invalid argument!'. For complement for my question, I get my database through private WRF model, so I am not sure it is OK to share it in online.
But after question this, I had some minor progress in my problem, let me specify my problem/question. I found out opening up NetCDF(.nc) file occurs error for 'wrong dim magic number' via 'Panoply', and find out this was indicating the header of the file(data before the ASCII label comes out) is corrupted or not matching with other header data. So, I opened my file in 'HxD' and speculate the header in hexadecimal form :
43 44 46 02
00 00 00 01
00 00 00 0D
0A 00 00 00
0D 0A 00 00
04 00
...
After asking to chatGPT and comparing with other manually processed NetCDF file's header, I confirmed this was the header layout.
43 44 46 : CDF = 'It is NetCDF file'
02 : 'This file format is CDF 64 bit offset'
00 00 00 01 : Unlimited dimension number (Time) is 01.
00 00 00 0D : I am not sure but it seems to be indicating Dimension size (GPT says it is related to some metadata)
0A 00 00 00 : Dimension number
0D 0A 00 00 00 04 : I am working out in this part (GPT says is it attribute/variable 's number + data padding)
What I want to ask is :

Is error 'dim magic number wrong' can be solved by manually fixing the header data?
Is my understanding in header format correct?
what do last 5 numbers refer to?

Sorry again for my short English and wrong question. Thanks always.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hi alodino, can you provide a link to where you got the data from?

Only including info like "error occurs "Invalid argument"" is not the least bit useful. Please prove the code that you used, plus full error trace backs. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Unclear if you've seen / read: https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-c/current/faq.html#How-many-netCDF-formats-are-there-and-what-are-the-differences-among-them

I really appreciate all of your answer sincerely. Although I am still having trouble in opening up, but I think this seems to be a problem in WRF model itself, so I requested a new version of file. Thank you very much.
